# Apache (internal dummy connection) crashes server with too many logs

Tags: apache, access-log

i know that this question is silly and often answered, but no solution worked for me by now. I'm using OpenSuse and Apache2 and added

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" loopback
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined env=!loopback
```

but if i restart the apache, the access log shows me

```
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:06 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:16 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:22 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:34 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:35 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:36 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:18:37 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:19:34 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [01/Nov/2012:23:19:52 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
```

Can someone help me please, because my server have much traffic and in this case, the dummy connections are very bad for performance of the server. Ask me anything you want to know about the server configs.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in third

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*internal dummy connection.*" loopback
```

Comment: Quick additional question on this (hope is not a wrong place) are those internal dummy connection going to fire my CMS causing it to connect to the DB? I'm reading a bunch of things about it, but I didn't understand if this "tick" sent by apache loads my site homepage or what?? I'm in a very similar situation, should I worry about this and add that line to my configuration? Thank you guys!